# sequelize keep saying it can't read property 'hasOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm working on an application to allow users to create teams for online games, but right now I am having a problem with my database. At the moment I have three models user, team and teamMembers.
The relations of the models are as follows Users can only be on one team, a team has a team captain which is represented as a foreign key in the Team model that references the User id, a team also has four other members which are connected from team model to user model through teamMembers which is a junction table.

The models can be seen below:

team.js

```
const sequelize = require('../db');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
//const { User } = require ('../models/user');
const { User } = require('./user');

class Team extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'captain' });
  }
}

Team.init(
  {
    teamId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    teamName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    captainId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'User',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Team',
  }
);

User.hasOne(Team, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'team' });
Team.associate = function(models) {
  Team.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'captain' });
};


// Function to create a new team with a given name and captain ID
async function createTeam(teamName, userId) {
  const team = await Team.create({ 
    teamName, 
    captainId: userId
  });
  return team;
}

module.exports = { Team, createTeam };
```

user.js:

```
const { Sequelize, sequelize, DataTypes } = require('../db');
const { hashPassword } = require('../auth');
const { Team } = require('../models/team');

// Define a User model with fields for email and hashed password
class User extends Sequelize.Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'team' });
  }
}

User.init(
  {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  }
);

// Function to create a new user with a hashed password
async function createUser(username, email, password) {
    const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);
    const user = await User.create({ email, username, password: hashedPassword });
    return user;
}
  
// Function to find a user by email and return the user object
async function findUserByEmail(email) {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    return user; 
}

async function findUserById(id) {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: { id },
    include: { model: Team, as: 'team' }
  });
  return user;
}
  
module.exports = { User, createUser, findUserByEmail, findUserById };
```

teamMembers.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql', 'root', 'test', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});

const TeamMembers = sequelize.define('TeamMembers', {});

module.exports = { TeamMembers };
```

The associations are made in the following file associations/index.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Team = require('../models/team');
const TeamMembers = require('../models/teamMembers');


User.hasOne(Team, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'team' });
Team.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'captain' });
Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: TeamMembers });
User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: TeamMembers });
```

I connect to the database in dbInit.js

```
const { sequelize } = require('./db');
const { User } = require('./models/user');
const { Team } = require('./models/team');
const { TeamMembers } = require('./models/teamMembers');

// Define associations
User.hasOne(Team, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'team' });
Team.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'captain' });
Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: TeamMembers });
User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: TeamMembers });

async function initDatabase() {
    try {
      // Sync the model with the database to create the necessary tables
      await sequelize.sync();
      console.log('All models were synchronized successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to initialize database:', error);
    }
}

module.exports = { initDatabase };
```

At the current moment my server wont even start after I refactored my code to get it to work, it used to work.

Here is my index.js

```
const { initDatabase } = require('./dbInit');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { signup, login } = require ('./authController');
const { verifyToken } = require ('./auth');
const { createUser, findUserByEmail, findUserById } = require ('./models/user');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

initDatabase().then(() =>{
    app.listen(5000, () => {
        console.log('Listening on http://localhost:5000');
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Hello World!!'
    });
});

app.post('/signup', signup);



app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const token = await login(req, res);
      res.cookie('token', token);
      res.json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.get('/team', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const userId = verifyToken(token);
        const user = await findUserById(userId);
        if (user && user.teamId) {
            const team = await findTeamById(user.teamId);
            res.json({
                inTeam: true,
                teamName: team.teamName
            });
    }   else {
            res.json({
            inTeam: false
        });
        }
    }   catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
```

And my error message if you need it

```
User.hasOne(Team, { foreignKey: 'captainId', as: 'team' });
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOne' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\svende-proeve\server\models\team.js:41:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\svende-proeve\server\models\user.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\svende-proeve\server\dbInit.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: You have circular imports

Comment: @DanielA.White how would I fix this I haven't worked that much with nodejs before

Comment: There’s plenty of questions out there